# Make other shapes from one cookie cutter

Tags: 3d-printing, stl

Is there a simple way to get other shapes of this cookie cutter (for example a heart or mitten), or would I have to start from scratch?
I only need to change the shape of the top part of the cutter.
I need it for 3d printing.
[image]

Comment: A heart is a completely different shape... of course you could try to move the exisiting geometry manually to get a heart shape, but building it new might be easier. There is no "make it heart-shaped" button in Blender and it is no primitive shape like a circle or a square, which might have made things a little easier...

Answer (score 1):

Select the top edge and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to hide the rest:

[image]

Then right click > *LoopTools* (you need to activate the *LoopTools* addon) > *Circle*:

[image]

Model your new shape (enable the *Proportional Editing* and the X symmetry options):

[image]

Unhide the rest (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you!